# expressJS promise and error handling

Tags: javascript, express, error-handling, promise, catch-block

I have a route that first need to query the database, then with the results, query another web service, then with that result render the page.
I have that flow worked out and am trying to figure out the error handling. Given that i talk to multiple service, I'm trying to massage the error before returning them to express.

Here is the structure of the code for the route:

```
Models.Episode.findById(request.params.episodeID)
    .catch(function (error) {
        throw (throwjs.notFound());
    })
    .then(function (episode) {
        if (episode.getUser().id !== request.user.href) {
            return next(throwjs.unauthorized("You do not have access to this podcast"));
        }
        return doSomeOtherAsyncStuff();
    })
    .then(function (queryResponse) {
        renderPage();
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        next(error);
    });
```

My problem is with the first catch. My goal in this catch is to repackage the error and stop the execution and send the error to express middleware.

With the way it is written above, the execution stops, but my express error handler are not called.

I tried rewriting the first catch as

```
.catch(function(error){
     return next(error);
})
```

But that does not solve the issue. The only solution i found is to move the catch to the end. But then i lose context of the failure location.

Any clue as to what i'm doing wrong?
Thanks, olivier

Comment: Did you actually rewrite the first catch as you did in your example? because there's a typo.

Comment: @Seth Good point, I retried just to make sure with the typo fixed and got the same issue.

Comment: @t.niese by having the catch early in the thread, i know the only thing that failed is the statement above. If i add the catch at the bottom only, then i'm not sure what failed

Comment: When you remove the first catch, you loose the context entirely? Unless two errors are occurring within the promise, that seems odd. `.catch` works similarly to `try/catch` in that you only need one. I don't recall ever needing the use of two `.catch`'s with my promise chains.

Comment: @Seth The scenario i'm thinking about is two then clause might throw different errors (let's say the first one is a database error, while the second then clause might be a server error from downloading a remote file). By having two catch clause, it's easy to know which error i'm handling. With a single catch, i have to handle both those error and figure out how to differentiate between the two.

Comment: In your promise chain, it doesn't look like a user can be authorized nor `doSomeOtherAsyncStuff` UNTIL you have a valid episode by ID.  You should simplify your controller by moving the episode lookup to a piece of middleware that is passed to the route before that controller, thus returning the correct error earlier and preventing the need for multiple catches. While you're at it, you should definitely validate users in their own piece of middleware as well. This logic is highly coupled and but does not need to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend taking a different approach so you don't have to rely on long running promise chains. With the following approach, you've decoupled your authorization and and validation to separate middleware, since they're not necessarily a concern of the actual episode handler itself. Plus this approach is more idiomatic to express.

An added bonus is that you're free to pass errors down to an error handler so you further decouple your errors from your route handlers.

```
function validateEpisode(req, res, next) {
  Models.Episode
    .findById(req.params.episodeID)
    .then(function(episode) {
      req.yourApp.episode = episode;
      next() // everything's good
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // would be better to pass error in next
      // so you can have a general error handler
      // do something with the actual error
      next(throwjs.notFound());
    });
}

function authUserByEpisode(req, res, next) {
  if (req.yourApp.episode.getUser().id !== req.user.href) {
    next(throwjs.unauthorized("You do not have access to this podcast"));
  }

  next(); // authorized
}

function episodeController(req, res) {
  // do something with req.yourApp.episode
}

app.get('/episode/:id', validateEpisode, authUserByEpisode, episodeController)
```

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to experiment with this. I'm still fairly new at that whole Express thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well after all, this is related to the throwjs framework I'm using and the fact that I'm using incorrectly

```
    throw (throwjs.notFound());
```

should be

```
    throw (new throwjs.notFound());
```

...